# mysql data node not connecting to node manager on AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-cluster

I am trying to setup mySql manager + data node + sql server (Server A) and another data node cluster on (Server B).
Both running on Ubuntu 16.04 amd_64

**Server A**

*/etc/hosts* also on Server B

```
Both private ip
172.xx.xx.xx ip-172-xx-xx-xx-eu-west-1.compute.internal
172.xx.xx.xx ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-east-1.compute.internal
```

*/config.ini*

```
[ndbd default]
 NoOfReplicas=2  # Number of replicas

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal <- Server A
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
NodeId=1

[ndbd]
hostname=ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal <- Server A
NodeId=3
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[ndbd]
hostname=ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-east-1.compute.internal <- Server B
NodeId=2
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[mysqld]
hostname=ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal <- Server A
```

*/etc/my.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysq_cluster]
ndb-connectstring = ip-172-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal <- Server A
```

**Server B**

*/etc/my.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=172.xx.xx.xx <- Server A private ip
```

**Server A error**

running ndbd gives me this error

```
[ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to '172.xx.xx.xx:1186'
[ndbd] ERROR    -- Failed to allocate nodeid, error: 'Error: Could not alloc node id at 172.xx.xx.xx port 1186: Connection done from wrong host ip 172.xx.xx.xx.'
```

**Server B error**

running ndbd gives me this error

```
Unable to connect with connect string: nodeid=0,172.xx.xx.xx:1186
Retrying every 5 seconds. Attempts left: 12
```

**ndb_mgm**

```
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: 172.xx.xx.xx:1186 <- A
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 1 node(s)
id=2 (not connected, accepting connect from 172.xx.xx.xx) <- B

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @172.x.x.x  (mysql-5.7.22 ndb-7.6.6)

[mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
id=3 (not connected, accepting connect from 172.xx.xx.xx) <- A
```

Not sure how would i connect to mysqld(API) that should work fine after i installed the server/client cluster.

Also i got inbound on both Instances A & B to accept all traffic between all port ranges 1000-60000 just in case i am missing something, and outbound is open to everything.

I wonder what is it i am missing, i got so tired today trying to find out what is going on with the setup.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Do not cross-post.  You are better off on dba.stackexchange com

Comment: Thank you and i will remove question from here, i just wanted to make sure i would get most helpful resources from both common related departments